# How to efficiently convert between unicode code points and UTF-8 literals in python?

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8

I have a large table of unicode code points: http://www.unicode.org/Public/UCD/latest/ucd/UnicodeData.txt

Which I would like to render, In order to do so: I understand the the code point has to be converted to a utf-8 literal string, and then that literal string (treated as a bytes object) can be converted into the character that I want to render.

As a concrete example given the hex number:

"00A1"

I need to convert it to the expression:

"\xc2\xa1"

And then from there it's easy in python to convert it to the character "¡".

My problem is how to convert from "00A1" to "\xc2\xa1" and vice and versa [ideally using built in methods or popular 3rd party libraries]

There doesn't appear to be a built in method to support that.

### My work so far:

The string.encode methods allows us to convert "¡" to a "\xc2\xa1"

The bytestring.decode method allows us to convert "\xc2\xa1" to a "¡"

But accessing that hex-index representation of the character (converting back and forth from 00A1) is unfortunately still out of reach for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually I don't think you need to go via utf-8 at all here. [`int`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) will give you the codepoint

```
>>> int('00A1', 16)
161
```

And then it's just [`chr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#chr)

```
>>> chr(161)
'¡'
```

Comment: If you *really* need UTF-8 you can encode it once you have the Unicode string: `chr(161).encode('utf-8')`.